# Не подтягивается картинка с помощью {{ contact.contact_image.ur }}

Tags: python, django

Проблема в том что приложение пытается тянуть картинку по ссылке

> /ref_pages/media/fbRostovay.jpg1.JPG

но доступна она по

> /media/fbRostovay.jpg1.JPG

приложение автоматом добавляет

> /ref_pages

Если я путь в MEDIA_URL = '/media/' меняю на MEDIA_URL = '/ref_pages/media/' то работает но тогда картинки не может получить другое приложение

в другом приложении все норм работает не пойму где я натупил,подскажите плс из-за чего это может быть

models.py

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals
from django.db import models


class Referer(models.Model):
    class Meta():
        db_table = "ref_pages_referer"

    ref_link = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    describe_link = models.TextField()
    free_test = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    personal_proxy = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    change_proxy = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    public = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    img = models.ImageField(default='img/q12.jpg')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.describe_link
```

views.py

```
from django.core.paginator import Paginator
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404, render

from .models import Referer


def category(request):
    return render(request, 'ref_pages/category.html')

def support(request):
    contact_list = Referer.objects.all()
    paginator = Paginator(contact_list, 2)  # Show 25 contacts per page
    page = request.GET.get('page')
    contacts = paginator.get_page(page)
    return render(request, 'ref_pages/index.html', {'contacts': contacts})
```

urls.py

```
from django.urls import path

from . import views

app_name = 'ref_pages'

urlpatterns = [
    path('category', views.category, name='category'),
    path('', views.support, name='index'),
]
```

settings.py

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'poll/static') # добавил для отображения новой админки
STATICFILES_DIRS = (os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static"),)

MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
```

Comment: Настройки django покажите

Comment: добавил,эта часть?

Comment: Покажите ещё шаблон, где пытается тянуть.

Comment: шаблон у меня только этот,я в логах вижу по какому пути он картинку пытается найти .Если я путь в MEDIA_URL = '/media/' меняю на MEDIA_URL = '/ref_pages/media/' то работает но тогда перестаёт работать в другом app,

Comment: А в админке URL тоже неправильное отображается?

Comment: Можете показать код шаблона `index.html`?

Comment: А если `app_name` в урлах убрать?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Django сам по себе в продакшене не заведует media файлами. Поэтому делается это следующим образом:
Папка media - корневая для файлов данного типа, а дальше в ней идет иерархия.

Поэтому все работает по адресу `/media/fbRostovay.jpg1.JPG`
Так и должно оставаться.

Вам следует переделать логику приложения, чтобы оно не добавляло к запрашеваему пути `/ref_pages`

Почему оно добавляет это слово в пути? Возможно, вы передаете в ссылку добавочный путь, без `/` в начале.
То есть если на текущей странице открыть ссылку `media/picture.jpg`, то откроется путь `current_path/media/picture.jpg`, а если открыть `/media/picture.jpg` (со слешем в начале), то путь таким и останется.

Возможно, проблема в чем-то еще, нужен код шаблона еще.

**Дополнительно**

Просто хранить все в папке media не хорошо. Если файлов будем много - все будет виснуть. Нужно раскидывать по папкам, поэтому в вашем

`img = models.ImageField(default='img/q12.jpg')`

добавьте параметр `upload_to`

Answer (score 2):

Попробуйте добавить в `urls.py` в папке проекта следующее:

```
from django.conf.urls.static import static

urlpatterns = [
    # ...
] + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```